# Problems with running neovim

Tags: neovim

I have some problems with running neovim. I don't know what I have done but it shows me this message: `nvim: /builddir/build/BUILD/neovim-0.5.0/src/nvim/ui_compositor.c:556: ui_comp_raw_line: Assertion 'attrs[i] >= 0' failed.` I tried to search for this problem on the internet but it gave me nothing.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: you built neovim from source? if yes, what commands you ran?

Answer (score 2):

it seems that you built neovim from source. i dont know how your process was like. but i will show the steps that i tried and worked for me.

try to rebuilt again with these instructions:

- clone 0.5
- run make
- run make install
- run `which nvim`

1. to clone

```sh
git clone --branch release-0.5 https://github.com/neovim/neovim
```

2. build

```sh
cd neovim
make
```

3. install

```sh
sudo make install
```

4. see the path of neovim

```sh
which nvim
```

tell me what happens after running these steps.

if it doesnt work, try another way.
clone the 0.6 release:

```sh
git clone https://github.com/neovim/neovim
```

repeat the steps; and tell me the results

Answer (score 0):

You can just download the pre-compiled binaries from the official [NeoVim GitHub release page](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/releases/).
Pay attention that **in this page you can also find the development version** which you may not want.

If you just want to download the **latest stable release**, go to the [NeoVim GitHub](https://github.com/neovim/neovim) and on the right you can find the **Releases** section which will show the latest stable version; click on that and you will be redirected to a page where you can download NeoVim in various format: **tar.gz**, **zip**, **appimage** ecc...

As for now you provided not enough information for helping you in the compiling process.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30221530)

Comment: I've added some information. Is it better this way?